# Probability of hits over long times

Tags: probability

A particular event occurs every minute, for instance. When this event starts, it is checked whether a random number (a float between `0.0` to `1.0`) is less or equal than `0.1`. If so, then an action occurs.

- Every minute: event generate a random number between `0.0` to `1.0`;
- If random number is `<=` to `0.1`, do action;
- Else, wait to next minute to try again;

I need know a formula that accept a number of cycles as variable and I receive the possibility to action occur.

- Cycle 1: 10% of chances;
- Cycle n: ...% of chances;
- Cycle 60: ...% of chances;

Answer (score 1):

**It solve my problem:** [Probability that a man will hit the target](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179357/probability-that-a-man-will-hit-the-target?rq=1)

Basically, I need reverse my initial possibility (10% will turn 90%) and pow with number of event cycles ("each minute"), so I reverse again to know my possibility:

> **possibility** = 1 - ( 1 - **initial possibility** ) ^ **number of cycles**

For instance, for first cycle, considering 10% of initial possibility:

- p = 1 - ( 1 - 0.1 ) ^ 1
- p = 1 - 0.9 ^ 1
- p = 1 - 0.9 = 10% of chances

For 10th cycle, still considering 10% of initial possibility:

- p = 1 - ( 1 - 0.1 ) ^ 10
- p = 1 - 0.9 ^ 10
- p = 1 - 0.349... = 65.1% of chances

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p+%3D+1+-+0.9+%5E+c%3B+c+from+1+to+100) reference.